# How to download a file over terminal when I don't know the explicit link?

Tags: ubuntu, curl, terminal, download, wget

I want to download [http://dreamdragon.github.io/PennAction/] over the terminal (ubuntu). I tried via `curl` and `wget` by adding `latest.tar.gz`, but it doesn't work. It's probably a stupid question, but hopefully someone can quickly tell me the answer in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you download the `tar.gz` and use the download tab of the browser, you can find the download url to be;

```
https://codeload.github.com/dreamdragon/PennAction/legacy.tar.gz/gh-pages
```

Using [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) with the `-O`, `-J` and `-L` options you can download the `tar.gz`

```sh
curl -O -J -L https://codeload.github.com/dreamdragon/PennAction/legacy.tar.gz/gh-pages
```

The 'magic' is due the `-J` option:

> -J/--remote-header-name
>
> (HTTP) This option tells the -O/--remote-name option to  use  the
> server-specified  Content-Disposition  filename instead of extracting a
> filename from the URL.